# Blocking recurring meetings for Room Mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

we'd like to block users from scheduling recurring meeting a room mailbox. All of our room/equipment mailboxes are locked down to 1080 days already.

room mailbox is configured with the following settings:

```
PSShowComputerName                  : False
AutomateProcessing                  : AutoAccept
AllowConflicts                      : False
BookingWindowInDays                 : 1080
MaximumDurationInMinutes            : 1440
AllowRecurringMeetings              : True
EnforceSchedulingHorizon            : True
ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours         : True
ConflictPercentageAllowed           : 0
MaximumConflictInstances            : 0
ForwardRequestsToDelegates          : True
DeleteAttachments                   : True
DeleteComments                      : True
RemovePrivateProperty               : True
DeleteSubject                       : False
AddOrganizerToSubject               : False
DeleteNonCalendarItems              : True
TentativePendingApproval            : True
EnableResponseDetails               : True
OrganizerInfo                       : True
ResourceDelegates                   : 
RequestOutOfPolicy                  : {}
AllRequestOutOfPolicy               : False
BookInPolicy                        : {}
AllBookInPolicy                     : True
RequestInPolicy                     : {}
AllRequestInPolicy                  : False
AddAdditionalResponse               : False
AdditionalResponse                  :
RemoveOldMeetingMessages            : True
AddNewRequestsTentatively           : True
ProcessExternalMeetingMessages      : False
RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications : False
```

Answer (score 3):

```
AllowRecurringMeetings : True
```

Have you tried setting this to `False`?

> [`Set-CalendarProcessing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-calendarprocessing?view=exchange-ps) `-AllowRecurringMeetings`
>
> The `AllowRecurringMeetings` parameter specifies whether to allow
>   recurring meetings. Valid input for this parameter is `$true` or `$false`.
>   The default value is `$true`.

Comment: Esa's suggestion is accepted, please have a try.